# Recursion - mystery1

Tags: java, recursion, trace

Having a tough time with the below code, I have answered the first call correctly as the condition is immediately correct. However, the second call of 4 is causing me great confusion, I came to the answer 2, 1 however it is incorrect- I am clearly getting things mixed up. Can someone explain to me exactly why my answer is wrong and the correct breakdown of the process of Recursive tracing in this example. I do understand elements of recursion however I am having issues following the process of tracing.

```
public void mystery1(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        System.out.print(n);
    } else {
        mystery1(n / 2);
        System.out.print(", " + n);
    }
}

mystery1(1);
mystery1(4);
mystery1(16);
```

Comment: How and why did you come to the answer 2,1? What part is confusing?  `n` is `4` when you pass in four. So clearly the last value will be a four....

Comment: did you understood the concept??

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I now understand thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion is beautiful yet very powerful and when it comes to observe it, people get tricked.

Let me explain you how i learnt it when i was preparing for my GATE(Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering).

Think of each Function call as **2 parts:**

1. Printing
2. Calling with halving itself

Now all the operations will be stacked upon the older one until unless we are out of recursion and only **Printing** is left in the function cycle.
We will print out in stack format **i.e FIFO**

Example, if we have these elements in stack:

Top: 
4
3
7
2
Bottom

It will print 4 3 7 2 .

**Now taking your Question:**

Lets break your Conditional statements in two halves, **1st** will be **if condition with Print** **2nd** will be **else with its print**.

**Note**: Only one part i.e 1st will print 1 and that too without commas (,).

I have attached the Image below kindly refer it, think as print statement as on stack, and the lowest print statement will be executed first as we will end out of function calls.

[image]

Now combining  mystery1(1),mystery1(4),mystery1(16) the final output will be: **1
1
, 2
, 4
1
, 2
, 4
, 8
, 16**

**PS: If you are going to give interviews of Amazon , Google or any Reputed Product based company they will ask question with flavor of recursion and that too without using any compiler, they wanna test your concepts via programming.**

Comment: Thank you so much for you detailed breakdown @Common Man this was very helpful I was getting things mixed in my head before but your example was so clear and easy to understand- the key thing I understood from your example was that in this process you are always working back to 1 form the argument that gets passed initially. this was exactly what I was getting stuck on which values to print out but you have cleared this up for me and I understand the process- thank you so much also for your diagram it helped me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

When you call mystery1(4), it goes to the else part and calls mystery1(2) since n>1. The print statement will be executed only after mystery1(2) has finished executing.

The same thing happens for mystery1(2) and it calls mystery1(1). It waits for mystery(1) to finish execution.

When mystery1(1) is called, it prints "1".

Then, mystery1(2) will continue and print ",2".

Finally, mystery1(4) will continue and print ",4".

So your output will be 1,2,4

Comment: makes so much sense now @Ayush Maharjan I now understand thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your method:

```
public static void mystery1(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        System.out.print(n);
    } else {
        mystery1(n / 2);
        System.out.print(", " + n);
    }
}
```

try to replace the position of `System.out.print(", " + n);` before `mystery1(n / 2);` call.

In the first case, when `System.out` after `mystery1` call, you have result as `1, 2, 4`, because, first you have to get result, then print it.

In the second case, when `System.out` before `mystery1` call, you have result as `, 4, 21`, because, first you print the result, then calculate the next result in function.

Comment: makes so much sense now @Bseitkazin I now understand thank you for your help.

Comment: @BillyAtim, you are welcome. if it is so, could you change the right answer mark?